# Replace a value in URL

Tags: text-processing, scripting, variable, replace

I'm new to Linux world and need some help. I have two files :

A token.txt file with a string something like this: `xd2111Vf124FfmrfJ22fag`

And a playlist.m3u file with the following:

```
EXTM3U
EXTINF:-1,Channel 1
EXTVLCOPT:network-caching=1000
http://myurl.com/index.m3u8?token=nd2451SVf124dfKwJ22sds

EXTM3U
EXTINF:-1,Channel 2
EXTVLCOPT:network-caching=1000
http://myurl.com/index2.m3u8?token=nd2451SVf124dfKwJ22sds
```

How can I replace all the token values in this file using the contents of the token.txt file which is getting updated. Appreciate all the answers...

I want to make a bash script and automate it with crontab later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed "/^http/s/=.*/=$(<token.txt)/" playlist.m3u
```

With the given example, this would produce

```
EXTM3U
EXTINF:-1,Channel 1
EXTVLCOPT:network-caching=1000
http://myurl.com/index.m3u8?token=xd2111Vf124FfmrfJ22fag

EXTM3U
EXTINF:-1,Channel 2
EXTVLCOPT:network-caching=1000
http://myurl.com/index2.m3u8?token=xd2111Vf124FfmrfJ22fag
```

The `sed` command first finds any line starting with `http` and then replaces everything after the first `=` on those lines with the contents of the file `token.txt` (this file should contain only the new token on one line).

This works by allowing the shell to expand the command substitution `$(<token.txt)` inside the replacement part of the substitution. This inserts the contents of the file in the `sed` expression.

To update the file in place, use `sed` with its `-i` option, or redirect the output to a new file and rename that:

```
sed "/^http/s/=.*/=$(<token.txt)/" playlist.m3u >new && mv new playlist.m3u
```

Removing the `^` from `^http` would make `sed` look for `http` anywhere in the line, not just at the beginning.  Remove `^` if you have further data in front of the URL.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for a detailed answer! :) This works perfect...

Comment: Can you please help me with the below as well?

Comment: Is it possible to make sed ignore the operation if the token is blank (empty file) ? This will ensure that the token is not overwritten with blank space in the playlist...

Comment: @KenthKvien You would have to test that separately: `test -s token.txt && sed ...`.